# How to print a part of an item in bold with JList

Tags: java, jlist

I use a `DefaultListCellRenderer` to render an array of Strings (its not really an array of Strings, its just to explain my question). The `getListCellRendererComponent` function take an Array and must print an element of that array in bold. My current idea is to use Html tags (like `<b>theElement</b>`) but I have read that this is not good practice. The code below is my current idea.

```
if (value instanceof ArrayList) {
     ArrayList<String> al = (ArrayList<String>) value   
     String s = "<html><b>" + al.get(0) + "</b></html>\n";
     al.remove(0);
     for(String c : al)
         s += c + "\n";
     setText(s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML in a JList, and I'm not aware of why that would be a bad practice - unless when the user selects a row, you are now checking whether the selected item is `<b>thing</b>` rather than just `thing`. But if you're doing something better than string comparisons on the selected list items, this shouldn't be a problem.

If you're using `DefaultListCellRenderer`, this is the only way I know that you can make some part of an item bold.

See also [Can Items in a JList be formatted as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070484/can-items-in-a-jlist-be-formatted-as-html)

Comment: OK I will do like that!